# what step should i choose to get needed precision in trapezoidal method

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

What step should i choose to get needed precision in trapezoidal method?

```
function Int = Trapezoidal(f, a, b, precision)
    h = sqrt(precision);
    n = (b - a) / h;
    y = f(linspace(a, b, n + 1));
    sum_y = sum(y) - 0.5 * (y(1) + y(end));
    Int = sum_y * h;
end

f = @(x)(x./(1+x.^4))
```

I thought, that if method has $O(h^2)$ error, then from desired precision i can take square root to get needed $h,$ but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: The amount of error really depends on the function `f` and how rapidly it is changing. I don't think there's a general method you can use to get some precision $\epsilon$ for an arbitrary function.

Comment: You may have seen an error bound in terms of $a$, $b$, and $n$ and the maximum $S$ of the absolute value of the second derivative. My memory is unreliable, but it is something like $\frac{|b-a|^3S}{12n^2}$. For general purposes, this bound is more or less useless.  The usual thing, for a *simple* program, is to compute say TRAP($8$), TRAP($16$), and so on until the difference between successive estimates is acceptably small. It turns out that in computing TRAP($2n$) you only need TRAP($n$) together with $n$ new function evaluations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard  error bound for TRAP that in principle could be used. If $|f''(x)|\le M$ on our interval, then the absolute value of the error, when we use a subdivision into $n$ equal parts, is $\le \frac{|b-a|^3}{12n^2}M$.

However, this bound can be difficult to use, particularly in an automated setting, and often produces error estimates that are  unduly pessimistic.

In practice, one computes TRAP($4$), TRAP($8$), TRAP($16$), and so on, comparing successive calculations until they differ by less than the desired error.  This is computationally efficient, since in computing TRAP($2n$) we can reuse the previously calculated TRAP($n$), so that we use only $n$ new function evaluations.

Comparison of successive trapezoidal estimates also enables us to often get dramatically improved estimates at little computational cost. For details, please search under *Richardson Extrapolation* and *Romberg Integration*.